# How hibernate should work for this scenario?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have Department entity which contains list of employees. Say departmentA has list of employees from employee1 to employee10.

```
Step 1
         Department dept=(Department)session.get(Department.class, 100); // Department A


Step 2

        List<Employee> employees = dept.getEmployees();// it contains employee 1 also
        Now get employee for id1 from above list and modify the address to address 2         

Step 3
        Employee emp_step_3=(Employee)session.get(Employee.class, 1); 
        //updates employee address address 3 with session.saveOrUpdate(emp_step_3);

Step 4      
        session.saveOrUpdate(dept);
```

Questions

1. Will employee 1 object under employees  list at step 2 will be same as emp_step_3 ?
2. Should query be fired at step 3 for employee id 1 as it has already been fetched at step 2?
3. Should address 2 or 3 be updated for employee 1 ?

FYI , I am using cascade all for all associations

Comment: Can you share your objects for Department and Employee please. This will help to get your question answered ... hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- Will employee 1 object under employees list at step 2 will be same
>   as emp_step_3 ?

Yes. If step 1 pulls all employees for that dept into the managed session, then the employee entities for that dept will be managed entity, so when you get one of those employees by ID, Hibernate will return the same entity. (Assuming cascade all)

> 2- Should query be fired at step 3 for employee id 1 as it has already
>   been fetched at step 2?

Not really, you already have the entity that represents the employee you want.

> 3- Should address 2 or 3 be updated for employee 1 ?

Is address a managed entity? Do you have cascade all on that? If you save employee whose address has changed, it will save the associated entity as well. (Again if cascade all, or cascade persist is on) Or you could just save the address, if it's a managed entity.

Furthermore, you can just do session.saveOrUpdate(employee), you don't have to save the "dept" if nothing has changed about it.

This is assuming that all these occur within the same session.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are right.This is how it should be. But actually this is not the behavour i am observing. Actually i am using JPA with hibernate as implementation . JPA uses entity manager instead of session. Are you aware if it can be problem ?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking. Am I aware if WHAT can be a problem? JPA specification was heavily influenced by Hibernate, and for the most part JPA specifies what the implementation MUST or SHOULD do and leaves some things up to the implementors like Hibernate and EclipseLink. What is the behavior you are experiencing? And can you share some code?